# How do I display a new word each time I click a button in Android?

Tags: arrays, string, button

I have 3 words: elephant, house and clap.
I have 2 Buttons: previous and next.
I have a TextView to display the words.
The TextView should display elephant at the beginning, then if I click next it should display house and if I click next again it should display clap.
If I click previous it should display house again.

How do I code that?
I thought about creating a string array:
String words[] = {"elephant", "house", "clap"};

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the code below. This assumes you have a basic knowledge of how an Android activity goes together, and you're already comfortable creating the buttons and textviews.

```
// Class fields:

private String[] strings = new String[]{"elephant", "house", "clap", "etc."};
private TextView display;



// In your onCreate():

display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
Button nextButton = findViewById(R.id.next_button);
Button prevButton = findViewById(R.id.prev_button);

nextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        moveString(1);
    }
});

prevButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        moveString(-1);
    }
});



// In the class:

public void moveString(int move) {
    int newString = currentString + move;
    if (newString >= strings.length) {
        // if the new position is past the end of the array, go back to the beginning
        newString = 0;
    }
    if (newString < 0) {
        // if the new position is before the beginning, loop to the end
        newString = strings.length - 1;
    }
    currentString = newString;
    display.setText(strings[currentString]);
}
```

Comment: It works great, Mark! Amazing how fast you were able to code that! Let's say I want to make it loop and start from the beginning again, is it easy to do?

Comment: Very easy to do - where I've written `return;` you could replace it with `currentString = 0;` to always go back to the beginning, or you could use two if statements to loop properly in each direction

Comment: Unfortunately I get the error message after reaching the last string: unfortunately the app has stopped. This is how the logcat looks like: 09-29 14:02:10.262    2135-2135/com.example.claudio.maxcanreadattheageof1 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.claudio.maxcanreadattheageof1, PID: 2135
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=50; index=50
            at com.example.claudio.maxcanreadattheageof1.StartingPoint.moveString(StartingPoint.java:65)
            at com.example.claudio.maxcanreadattheageof1.StartingPoint$2.onClick(StartingPoint.java:50)

Comment: Could you post the code you're using in the moveString method? I'll take a look.

Comment: public void moveString(int move) {
        int newString = currentString + move;
        //if (newString<0 || newString >= strings.length) {
        if (newString >= strings.length) {
            //return;
            currentString=0;
        }
        currentString= newString;

        display.setText(strings[currentString]);
    }

Comment: Do you want it to loop around in both directions?

Comment: I changed the code, unfortunately I still get the error "unfortunately the app has stopped" once I reach the end of the array.

Comment: It crashed again. I really appreciate your help, Mark. If you want I can show you the problem via Skype by sharing my screen with you. My Skype id is: mitico2051

Comment: If I keep clicking previous, it loops without problems :-) but if I click next, after I reach the last string position, the app crashes.

Comment: I changed the newString> strings.length to newString>= strings.length and now it loops on both sides!!! Yes!!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! Apologies, one of my edits was mislead - I've fixed it now, so this is correct for anyone who comes in the future.